# Removing Special Characters and Numbers for a column in a data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, gsub

I have a data frame:

```
dput(Data1)
structure(list(Emp.ID = c(182038L, 191854L), Project.Acquired.Skill = structure(c(2L, 
1L), .Label = c("Architecting (10),Cognos TM1 (4),Support Function (3)", 
"SAS (76),SAS Analytics (76),SAS BI (76),SAS data modeling tool (63),ClearCase (18),SQL (18),SQL Server (18),SQL SERVER 2000 (18),SQL SERVER 2005 (18),Excel (16),Oracle (16),AS400 (10)"
), class = "factor")), .Names = c("Emp.ID", "Project.Acquired.Skill"
), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))

str(Data1)
'data.frame':   2 obs. of  2 variables:
 $ Emp.ID                : int  182038 191854
 $ Project.Acquired.Skill: Factor w/ 2 levels "Architecting (10),Cognos TM1 (4),Support Function (3)",..: 2 1
```

I have a column which is a factor with value like this `Architecting (10),Cognos TM1 (4),Support Function (3)` and i need to strip the numbers(0-9),WhiteSpace and the brackets() to get `Architecting,Cognos TM1,Support Function`. I am facing issues as this was coded as factor.
My output should look like this

```
Emp ID  Project Acquired Skill
182038  SAS,SAS Analytics,SAS BI,SAS data modeling tool,ClearCase,SQL,SQL Server,SQL SERVER 2000,SQL SERVER 2005,Excel,Oracle,AS400
191854  Architecting,Cognos TM1,Support Function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a character class regexp in `gsub`:

```
transform(Data1, Project.Acquired.Skill=gsub("\\s[0-9()]+","",Project.Acquired.Skill))
  Emp.ID
1 182038
2 191854
                                                                                             Project.Acquired.Skill
1 SAS,SAS Analytics,SAS BI,SAS data modeling tool,ClearCase,SQL,SQL Server,SQL SERVER,SQL SERVER,Excel,Oracle,AS400
2                                                                          Architecting,Cognos TM1,Support Function
```

Answer (score 2):

```
(data1[,2] <- gsub("\\s\\(\\d+\\)", "", data1[,2]))
# [1] "SAS,SAS Analytics,SAS BI,SAS data modeling tool,ClearCase,SQL,SQL Server,SQL SERVER 2000,SQL SERVER 2005,Excel,Oracle,AS400"
# [2] "Architecting,Cognos TM1,Support Function"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(qdap)
gsub(" ,", ",", strip(Data1[, 2], char.keep=",", lower=F))

## [1] "SAS,SAS Analytics,SAS BI,SAS data modeling tool,ClearCase,SQL,SQL Server,SQL SERVER ,SQL SERVER ,Excel,Oracle,AS"
## [2] "Architecting,Cognos TM,Support Function"
```